# Pandas DataFrame - list columns with lowest distinct values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code to find the columns in a data frame with the lowest number of distinct values and list them.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [2,3,4],"C":[1,1,2],"D":[3,3,4]})
print(df)
unique_counts = df.nunique()

lowest_distinct = 100
#
#Find the lowest distinct count across all columns
#
for column_name, distinct_count in unique_counts.iteritems():

    if distinct_count < lowest_distinct:
        lowest_distinct = distinct_count

lowest_distinct_columns = []
#
#Collect the columns having that count
#
for column_name, distinct_count in unique_counts.iteritems():

    if distinct_count == lowest_distinct:
        lowest_distinct_columns.append(column_name)

#
#Get the columns and values returned as a data frame
#
melted_df = df.melt(value_vars=lowest_distinct_columns,var_name='column', value_name='value')

print(melted_df)
```

It feels a bit clunky so I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it?  Ultimately I'm trying to get a list of the columns and values that have the lowest number of distinct values.

Any thoughts or tips appreciated.

Cheers

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it do what you want:

```
unique_counts = df.nunique()
lowest_distinct = unique_counts.min()
lowest_distinct_columns = unique_counts[unique_counts == lowest_distinct].index.tolist()

result = pd.DataFrame({col: df[col].unique() for col in lowest_distinct_columns})
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer.  Yes it almost does what I'm looking for - the final piece is to output the unique values for those columns as well.  Is that possible in this way?

Comment: I have edited the answer to output it as a dataframe with only the distinct values for each column of `lowest_distinct_columns`

Comment: perfect, thank you.  I'm still getting my head around the power of list comprehensions.  Very slick.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For older versions of pandas (< v.20), consider `apply` to return a series:

```
unique_ser = df.apply(lambda col: col.nunique(), axis=0)
print(unique_ser)
# A    3
# B    3
# C    2
# D    2

lowest_unique_ser = unique_ser[unique_ser == unique_ser.min()]
print(lowest_unique_ser)
# C    2
# D    2

final_ser = df[lowest_unique_ser.index].apply(lambda col: col.unique().tolist(), axis=0)
print(final_ser)
# C    (1, 2)
# D    (3, 4)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for this, as with the other answers is it possible to output the unique values with the column names having the lowest distinct values?

Comment: Great thank you.  This is exactly what I need and a good alternative to the one posted by Prikers.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
In [114]: df[unique_count[unique_count == unique_count.min()].index].melt(
                var_name='column', value_name='value')
Out[114]:
  column  value
0      C      1
1      C      1
2      C      2
3      D      3
4      D      3
5      D      4
```

Comment: Great, thank you.  Is it possible to add something to this one liner that will return the unique column and value combinations?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses.  The 3 solutions to the first part of the problem work equally well and the 2 responses to the second part of the problem also work very well.

I'll need to use them in practice to see if there is any material difference in performance or behaviour but to summarise the complete solutions:

@Parfait's solution:

```
unique_ser = df.apply(lambda col: col.nunique(), axis=0)
print(unique_ser)
# A    3
# B    3
# C    2
# D    2

lowest_unique_ser = unique_ser[unique_ser == unique_ser.min()]
print(lowest_unique_ser)
# C    2
# D    2

final_ser = df[lowest_unique_ser.index].apply(lambda col: col.unique().tolist(), axis=0)
print(final_ser)
# C    (1, 2)
# D    (3, 4)
```

and @Priker's

```
unique_counts = df.nunique()
lowest_distinct = unique_counts.min()
lowest_distinct_columns = unique_counts[unique_counts == 
lowest_distinct].index.tolist()

result = pd.DataFrame({col: df[col].unique() for col in lowest_distinct_columns})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [2,3,4],"C":[1,1,2],"D":[3,3,4]})
print(df1)
unique_counts = df1.nunique()

   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  1  3
1  2  3  1  3
2  3  4  2  4

unique_counts[unique_counts==unique_counts.min()]

C    2
D    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please explain the approach as well.